# How to cast string into Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#

I have 7 dropdown lists for the the hours of the day for each each day.

Instead of typing `datasource`, `textfield`, and `valuefield` for each drop down, I decided to create a small code that will iterate through an enum and append at the end the day of the week.

However I get an error : `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.`

The line `((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataSource = TimesAvailable();` Doesn't show any error at run time.

```
enum Days
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 3,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 5,
    Friday = 6
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    foreach (Days day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)))
    {
        object strTimeFrom = "ddlTimeFrom" + day;
        object strTimeTo = "ddlTimeTo" + day;

        ((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataSource = TimesAvailable();
        ((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataTextField = "Value";
        ((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataValueField = "Key";
        ((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataBind();
    }
}

protected List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> TimesAvailable()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> lstTime = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    lstTime.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(-1, "--Select Time---"));

    for (int intCnt = 1; intCnt <= 12; intCnt++)
    {
        lstTime.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(intCnt, intCnt.ToString()));
    }

    return lstTime;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`strTimeFrom` is a string (the name of the control I assume) so you can't just cast it into a dropdownlist.

You'll need to get an *instance* of the control, and since you know it's name you can use FindControl.

```
var strTimeFrom = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ddlTimeFrom" + day);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cant cast a string to a dropdownlist. Pretty simple

Comment: That's what I did: ((DropDownList)strTimeFrom).DataSource = TimesAvailable()

Comment: object strTimeFrom = "ddlTimeFrom" + day;

This object is a string. If you try to cast it to a dropdownlist it will FAIL.

Comment: Why have people downvoted this guy ? There is no implicit cast from String to DropDownList ! He is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that at runtime because you're trying to cast a string to a DropDownList. You might think that declaring `strTimeFrom` as object, and appending the day name to get your actual DropDownList, is going to work - but it won't. At the end of the day, `strTimeFrom/To` are strings and you cannot cast those as DropDownList.

In your case, you should declare these variables as string, and try

```
var list = Page.FindControl(strTimeFrom) as DropDownList;
list.DataSource = TimesAvailable();
list.DataTextField = "Value";
list.DataValueField = "Key";
list.DataBind();
```

As a rule you should not declare variables as object, particularly if you really want intrinsic types due to the boxing overhead. C# is a strongly-typed language; you need to be more specific.

Declaring variables as object just to get your code to compile suggests to me you need to do some more reading on C# fundamentals.

Comment: You are right. I use object for testing purposes to see if it work the most general case.
var strTimeFrom = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ddlTimeFrom" + day);  would work except the file is a user control.

Thanks for the quick reply everyone.

Comment: Yes, but you must have known that strTimeFrom and strTimeTo were going to be strings - because you were assigning a string literal + day to them in the declaration. Or did you not realize this, and think that you were assigning an actual control to strTimeFrom ? Either way, not going to work in a strongly-typed language my friend.

Comment: Yes I knew it was a string but the mistake was that trying to cast it with (Dropdown) was the wrong way.